# download attribute of the anchor element not honored in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, anchor

The download attribute on an anchor  element should set the name of the downloaded resource to the value of the download attribute. In the current version of chrome, the download attribute doesn't, however, change the name. Is this not anymore supported? Anything changed?

Here is a post explaining the functioning of the download attrib: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download

If it worked as expected, the name of the downloaded resource would be MyGoogleLogo. It is, however, the last element (file) of the href.

Comment: Worked for me in chrome 34

Comment: It used to work for me, now I have chrome Version 35.0.1916.114

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `download` attribute works only when the resource is retrieved via HTTP from the same server as the linking document. So if you have

```
<a href=foo.txt download=something.txt>xxx</a>
```

on a web page, it works, but if it is in a local file, it does not; neither does it work if a web page refers to a resource on another server. By “works” I mean setting the filename; even when it does not “work” in this sense on Chrome (or Firefox), it causes a pure download instead of navigation to the resource, i.e. the resource is downloaded as a file but not opened in the browser.

According to [MDN info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), “In Firefox 20 this attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin.” This seems to apply to current Firefox, too, in the stronger sense that the `download` attribute is completely ignored for cross-origin requests.

Comment: In my case, I generate the file in browser using js. Is this also considered cross-origin?